# Tables with engines of "MEMORY" does not get dropped when server is restarted

Tags: mysql, database-engine

I read a description from [When to Use MEMORY or NDB Cluster](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/memory-storage-engine.html)
from the MySQL website.

> Operations involving transient, non-critical data such as session
>   management or caching. When the MySQL server halts or restarts, the
>   data in MEMORY tables is lost.

but my created tables with ENGINES = MEMORY were not dropped upon mysql server restart.

CREATE TABLE `MY_TEMPORARY_TABLE` (
  `COLUMN_1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `COLUMN_2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `COLUMN_3` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: MySQL version? What is `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}` of the tables?

Comment: Was there any data in the table after the restart?

Comment: Both MEMORY and NDB are rarely used.  The only Engine that the typical user needs to care about is InnoDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every table created with `CREATE TABLE` will create a `.frm` file followed by other files (such as `.MYD` and `.MYI` for MyISAM or `.ibd` for InnoDB).

When it comes to a table created with `ENGINE=MEMORY` will create only the `.frm` file and actual data and index storage will occur in RAM.

If mysqld crashes, the data will be lost, but the `.frm` will remain.

In your case, you ran `CREATE TABLE MY_TEMPORARY_TABLE`. This will create a file called `MY_TEMPORARY_TABLE.frm`.

Had you created the table using `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE MY_TEMPORARY_TABLE`, then the table itself would disappear upon mysqld crash or shutdown.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation.